# Input Fields not showing up from a Model in Django forms

Tags: python, django

I'm new to python and Django. I'm trying to display a form which shows the fields from a model. the model and form are different apps.

here is my Users Model

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Users(models.Model):
first_name=models.CharField(max_length=128)
last_name=models.CharField(max_length=128)
email=models.EmailField(max_length=256,unique=True)
```

here is my forms.py from registerapp

```
from django import forms
from apptwo.models import Users

class NewUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
    model = Users
    fields= '__all__'
```

here is my views.py from registerapp

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from registerapp.forms import NewUserForm
from apptwo.views import index
def register(request):
    form=NewUserForm()
    if request.method=="POST":
        form =NewUserForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)
            return index(request)
        else:
            print("error form invalid")
    return render(request,'registerapp/register.html')
```

my register.html file

```
<div class="container">
        <h1>Register here</h1>
        <form method="POST">
            {{ form.as_p }}
            {%csrf_token%}
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="submit">
        </form>
</div>
```

this is what i'm getting
    [register.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKwQD.png)

please help me find my mistakes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`render()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) method takes `context` argument which contains dict of template's variables and its values. You forgot to pass your form with template context. You need to define context like this `context = {'form': form}` and pass it as `render's` argument.

```
def register(request):
    form=NewUserForm()
    if request.method=="POST":
        form =NewUserForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)
            return index(request)
        else:
            print("error form invalid")
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request,'registerapp/register.html', context)
```